# how to use colspan inside td element to display around 20 checkbox values fetched from database in php and html

Tags: php, html

how to display 20 check box element fetched from database horizontally  inside a TD  using col span. Am  using php for fetching data from database.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Act Name</td>
        <td colspan="5"><input type='text'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Industry Type</td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <?php 
                $conn=get_dbconnect();
                $sql="SELECT id,name FROM industry"; //selection query
                $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                    echo "<br> <input type='checkbox'  name='industrytype' value='".$row['name']."' onclick=checkAll(); /> ".$row['name'];
                   }
                }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show us your code, we will take it from there

Answer (score 0):

Create a div inside your `td`, make its style `display:flex` and then add `flex:1;` style to your checkboxes

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3CSTYLE%3E%5Cn%5Cttd%20%3E%20div%20%7Bdisplay:%20flex;%7D%5Cn%5Cttd%20%3E%20div%20input%20%7Bflex:%201;%7D%5Cn%3C/STYLE%3E%5Cn%3Ctable%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3EAct%20Name%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20colspan=%225%22%3E%3Cinput%20type='text'%3E%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3EIndustry%20Type%3C/td%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20colspan=%225%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C?php%5Cn%20$i=%200;%5Cn%5Cn%20while($i%20%3C%2010)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20echo%20%22%3Cbr%3E%20%3Cinput%20type='checkbox'%20name='industrytype'%20value='test-%22.$i.%22'%20onclick=checkAll();%20/%3E%20test-%22.$i;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20$i%2B%2B%20%20;%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20?%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3C/div%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C/td%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C/table%3E%5Cn%5Cn)**

Comment: i want to display first 5 checkbox elements in one td ,next 6 check box in another td .

Comment: In your original question, you said you want to display _'20 check box '_